# Is it possible to make a cross-domain AJAX call on Mobile Browsers?

Tags: iphone, android, ajax, mobile, cross-domain

I have a site which makes SOAP requests to a separate domain using YUI's cross-domain AJAX transport. This is working wonderfully on my site, but unfortunately since mobile browsers don't support flash, I can't get it to work.

Does anyone know of a way to make cross-domain AJAX posts on mobile browsers?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure what do you want to use extra header size of SOAP in mobile communication? It is a great overhead

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a javascript library such as jQuery JSONP is able to make GET requests to different domains.

I've also heard that mobile Safari isn't too strict on making cross-domain ajax calls anyway, though I haven't tried it myself.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

For me SOAP worked for Safari but did not work in Chrome (Android). AJAX did work for both.